# Netsuite custom form

Tags: netsuite-rest-api

I want to create a custom form, basically the form is to select stock that will be write off. That form should have a subtab. Under this subtab I want to have a button that will add one item followed by a new line if the button is pressed again. I am new to NetSuite and I am struggling to code this part.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH6t6.png)

I have created a custom form script. I have added a sublist that have the button add items and the four fields. And I tried to populate the filed via a save search. I am not sure if my idea will have the wanted outcome.

update: I have succeeded to create the entire form but struggling to add the sublist values to the custom record.
I tried to use record.setCurrentSublistValue() but my custom record doesn't have a sublist.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.